# Vue 3 how to access ref from another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have several component that I use in a component called QuickButton.vue:

```
<Tabs>
  <TabPanels>
          <TabPanel><EmployeesMainData/></TabPanel>
          <TabPanel><ContactAddressData/></TabPanel>
          <TabPanel><EmploymentData/></TabPanel>
          <TabPanel><AdditionalData/></TabPanel>
  </TabPanels>
      <div>
            <button type="submit" @click="signUp">Save</button>
      </div>
</Tabs>
```

this is EmployeeMainData code:

```
<template>
            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                <label for="email-address" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Email address</label>
                <input id="email-address" v-model="email" type="email" autocomplete="email" required
                class="appearance-none rounded-md relative block w-full my-4 px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Email address">
                <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500">*Required</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4 mb-2">
                <label for="password" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Password</label>
                <input id="password" v-model="password" type="text" required
                class="appearance-none rounded-md relative block w-full my-4 px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Password">
                <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500">*Required</p>
                <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500">*Password is used for employee to login into their Android app. Save and share the password to the employee.</p>
            </div>
</template>
```

How do I access email and password input using ref and script setup from `QuickButton.vue`? I already trying using `defineExpose` but didnt work

Comment: You likely shouldn't. Use two-way binding with v-model to provide data from EmployeesMainData to a parent.

Comment: @EstusFlask how do I achieve that? im still new to Vue

Comment: You can start with checking this chapter https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

Answer (score 0):

This chapter in the Vue docs contains information on v-model and using it with form input: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html. (Btw, the Vue docs are amazing! If you want to level up fast, review it a chapter or two at a time :).

Comment: is my EmployeeMainData.vue is commonly used as component? or I should put all the input inside QuickButton.vue

Comment: Hi Avocado, I don't think it really matters because the component will be swapped out for its template markup. So whether you have the raw template out there, or if you have a component encapsulating the template, the end result is the same. Creating the EmployeeMainData as a component would reduce your QuickButton.vue's code size, however, and make it easier to read, if that's important to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).